# Swift deinit was not called on created thread. How to fix?

Tags: swift

Swift deinit was called on background thread, however the object was created on the main thread. Is it guaranteed, that deinit is called in the same thread as init?

Comment: In trying to test this, I just found a memory leak! More to the point though, the Swift Book doesn't say either way. But if your tests do show that deinit is *not* guaranteed to be called on the same thread as init.

Comment: What are you doing for which this even matters?

Comment: @nhgrif I cancel network requests in RequestManager

Comment: @nhgrif It matters because of data races. I currently have big issues with this, albeit in a not that simple scenario. But basically it's due to that fact that `deinit` accesses member variables. If these have been modified previously by an operation executing on a different thread, and if these two threads happen to be not synchronised, then a data race occurs. And, it is a misconception that all operations are visible to the thread that executes `deinit` just because that `deinit` will be called when the last reference ceases to exist.

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, no it's not guaranteed.

With [ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) it will be called from the thread in which the last reference is found. Honestly, I would strongly discourage the use of this method unless you have a pretty good grasp of how ARC works and how it affects your code.